# No permission to access to any usb drive

Tags: permissions, users, usb-drive

On Ubuntu 20.04 recently cloned from a USB drive to my internal SSD, I can't access to any USB drive. It gives me [image: this message] for every USB sticks I plug into my computer.

I verified that I had access to them from other computers, and even from my Ubuntu session installed on my old USB stick. It seems I don't have the access rights only from my new Ubuntu installation.
I imagine it could comes from a special status my `user` doesn't have. Help to clarify that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am pretty sure you did not clone the *file access control list* of the subdirectories in `/media` (this happened to me before); just a plain recursive copy (or *rsync*) does not do that by default.

Here is what it looks like on my machine:

```
[sh @ balrog] / 29 % ls -ld /media
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jul 22  2018 /media

[sh @ balrog] / 30 % ls -l /media 
total 4
drwxrwx---+ 2 root root 4096 Mär  1 13:26 sh

[sh @ balrog] / 31 % getfacl /media/sh
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: media/sh
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:sh:rwx
group::r-x
mask::rwx
other::---
```

*Notice the `user:sh:rwx` line which is for my user account named "sh".*

I.e. even though the subdirectory `/media/sh` for my user account *sh* is owned by *root*, it has special FACL (file access control list) permissions. This is what you need to restore on your machine for your user account.

For a user named *kilroy*, you would do this:

```
cd /media
sudo mkdir kilroy
sudo setfacl -m u:kilroy:rwx kilroy
```

Notice that `/media/kilroy` is still owned by *root* and belongs to group *root*, but it now has additional permissions *rwx* (read, write and execute) for user *kilroy*. Check with

```
getfacl /media/kilroy
```

More info on the commands with `man setfacl` or `man getfacl`.

If you don't have those commands, install package `acl`:

```
sudo apt install acl
```

Comment: please use `$USER` in commands and variables and not `killroy` the 1st will automatically change to the current user.

Comment: @Rinzwind: At the cost of much less clarity because special characters get in the way. I intentionally chose not to do that. In some cases, you might have to write `${USER}` instead of simply `$USER` to avoid ambiguities. This is when weird syntax obscurs what the explanation is all about.

Answer (score 1):

I found out [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/801856/1187373) I just have to change the owner of `/media/$USER`.

To do that, I entered the command `sudo chown $USER /media/$USER`.
If the problem of access only concerns one drive the command is `sudo chown $USER /media/$USER/{drive}` where {drive} is the one you want to access to.

Comment: please use `$USER` in commands and variables and not `{username}` the 1st will automatically change to the current user.

Answer (score 0):

If your installation was cloned from another device then there is a good possibility that you have an errant mount point in your `/media/$USER` directory.

Try this:

1. Unplug any USB devices you may have connected
2. Examine the `/media/$USER` directory, where `$USER` is your username
3. Delete any directories that you find in there (assuming they're empty, which they should be)
4. Verify that `/media/$USER` is owned by your account
5. Connect a USB stick and test that you have permission to use it

If the `/media` location for your account is not writable or has locations left behind from elsewhere, this sort of issue can manifest.

Comment: Whoops. Terrible typo. Should have been `/media/{username}`, not `/mount`. Apologies 

Comment: How can I verify my account is the owner of `/media/{username}` ?  The command `ls -l` only display `total 0` in my case

Comment: please use `$USER` in commands and variables and not `{username}` the 1st will automatically change to the current user.