# All USB drives give This Location Could Not Be Displayed after distro-upgrade and Aptik Restore

Tags: upgrade, usb, permissions, backup, external-hdd

Yesterday, I installed a clean upgrade to 22.04 and restored my most recent backup using Aptik. Since then, whenever I try to view the contents of any connected USB drive in Nautilus, I get an error reading

> This could not be displayed.
> You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of "USBdrivename".

On a previous upgrade I had the same experience, my guess is it has to do with how the Aptik restore works, and I was able to find a fix in the forums. But after searching a long time and seeing similar but not yet identical issues, I haven't found whatever did the trick last time. What do I do? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well, I finally found [a case near identical to mine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1320624/no-permission-to-access-to-any-usb-drive), and the answer provided there also worked for me. The explanation for the problem after restoring a clone was

> I am pretty sure you did not clone the file access control list of the subdirectories in /media (this happened to me before); just a plain recursive copy (or rsync) does not do that by default.

Rather than changing ownership of /media/$USER from root to $USER (`sudo chown $USER /media/$USER`), as many such similar answers direct—which I saw some commentary, if I understood it correctly, could create an unnecessary security vulnerability...—I followed the guidance to restore read, write, and execute permissions, which was, essentially:

```
cd /media
sudo setfacl -m u:$USER:rwx $USER
```

This resolved my problem.

Comment: Thanks, this can be useful to others.